# Deployment and Application do not have matching Security Zones

Tags: windows-10, installation, dll, file-corruption

I am trying to install a piece of software from a Application Manifest. I get an error of the following:

> Application cannot be started. Contact the application vendor.

After contacting the vendor, the answer is that there is a corrupt file on my machine (Windows 10).

I also looked at detailed information in the error message.

**Summary:**

```
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Users\.... resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Deployment and application do not have matching security zones.
```

**Detail:**

```
Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [2/25/2017 12:12:07 AM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (Zone)
        - Deployment and application do not have matching security zones.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
```

When researching the issue, there are many application developers on stackoverflow (and other sites) working to resolve corrupted files. But none of them were from the end user standpoint.

My question is: How do I figure out which file is corrupt? And how do I fix that file?

Comment: If the vendor says a file is corrupt, he or she should be able to tell you which one is corrupt. If they cannot, they are guessing and did not provide you with any useful information.

Comment: Note: this is one of those questions where the non-accepted answer is likely to be more helpful (practically speaking at least) than the accepted one.

Comment: Can't answer this question officially without having another 9 reputation - The solution for me was that when the application is published, there are 2 files and a folder that are created. All of these need to be on the host computer for the application to install. I also can't take credit if this works for you as it took my tutor to point out that I had neglected to notice the `Application Files` folder that was created in addition to the `Setup.exe` and  `fileFoo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrongly tagged as a Windows 10 issue, when it is actually an issue that applies to all versions of Windows.

*Deployment and application do not have matching security zones* means there is a mis-match between the security settings in the deployment environment - i.e. your Windows O/S, and those embedded in the .exe application you are trying to run.

Detecting such a mis-match is a basic security feature, common to all versions of Windows (going all the way back to Windows 98). If the O/S thinks the program being run is a security risk, it isn't going to run it.

The answer to the question being asked, of course, is that there is **no solution**.

This error, in *many* (though not all) of its various manifestations, informs the user to contact the application vendor: this is because (and is an *admission* of the fact that) this error has no user solutions. It can only be resolved by the developer.

If you're getting the error, it means Windows doesn't think the developer has signed the manifests. The developer has likely failed, in the Signing tab, to check/tick the check box; and/or has failed to select a *valid* security certificate; and/or has failed to publish the software as Full Trust (but only as partial trust). (There are other possibilities too, but those are the obvious ones.) Such errors are developer errors, so can't be fixed by the end-user.

Comment: This accepted answer does not seem to be always correct, as at least for a few people the solution from the other answer worked: https://superuser.com/a/1303057/11875.

Comment: The _other_ answer implies that the .exe application file is valid, or is not, depending on which browser you download it with. That _cannot_ be so, because doing that makes no change in the .exe file. The problem I discuss is about the O/S rejecting the .exe file, but the choice of which _browser_ to use for the download is irrelevent to that issue. What is probably occuring in the _other_ answer is that Firefox has its (optional) security settings mis-set, so that Firefox is _mistaking_ the .exe file for a security risk, so refuses to download it. That is a very _different_ problem.

Comment: the _other_ answer offered a solution that did work for me personally, however now that you mention it, the sequence is indeed somewhat different between the browsers. In my case, there's a Miscrosoft Web application, which provides a certain _link_ on the menu. In Firefox and Chrome, clicking that link results in _downloading_ of an .application file - the file which then refuses to launch same exception as in OP's question. Clicking the same link in IE. however, does not result in a download, but rather immediate launch of the app, possibly with different security settings.

Comment: Sounds like the security settings in your _Firefox_ browser are doing a good job - I was wrong to describe them as possibly mis-set, if what they are doing is _preventing_ the .exe file from running. A browser must always _only_ download an executable file! It should _never_ run/launch the file, because that represents a major security risk. The .exe file would run before you've had a chance to check it with an anti-virus program to find out whether it's safe or whether it's infected with a virus! Internet Explorer, as always, is a bad security risk - _don't_ use it!

Comment: Agreed Sergii, but, only MS Edge worked for me in my situation: https://superuser.com/a/1303057/247728

Answer (score 36):

In my case (Microsoft Office 365 eDiscovery Export Tool), the error appeared when downloading the file with Firefox. I switched to Internet Explorer to download and start the .application file and then the installation succeeded.

Update: Also works with Edge.

Comment: This was my issue too.

Comment: Same with a Telerik demo installer: works in IE but neither Firefox nor Chrome. Thanks.

Comment: Same here. Worked with IE

Comment: Same here, worked for me when I switched to IE.

Comment: Firefox believes the installer file is a security risk, so refuses to allow the installer to start; but Internet Explorer recklessly runs the installer, exposing your computer to any malware hidden in the installer.

Comment: @Ed999 that is nonsense - its a click to run app, not an exe.

Comment: Nice, quick find and quick quick fix.

Comment: This works in MS Edge!  To get the error to go away about "Deployment and application do not have matching security zones" it only worked in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: @Ed999 or Firefox & chrome have got a bug or behaviour which is causing a valid file to be marked in their minds as insecure, while Internet Explorer runs it just fine. There isn't sufficient evidence to say one way or another

Comment: /facepalm. still an issue near the end of 2021. thanks for the answer

Comment: Yup, `Microsoft Office 365 eDiscovery Export Tool` just got me too! However, I used Edge rather than IE to resolve. This issue occurred for me when using Chrome. Thank you for this answer +1. The MS tool only like the MS browsers for this click once app.

Comment: Still an issue in End of 2022. At-least the big guy now decided to mention this while exporting: https://imgur.com/a/GgKCzhN

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: End of 2023 - Still an issue.  Dear Microsoft - I already have edge installed, what more do you want?

Answer (score 0):

The general answer, at least for the e-Discovery path - Run the browser as an administrator.  Of course, if you are going to do that, you might as well use Edge.

Then you'll run into other problems -

1. you have to have 'export' permissions, which you can get as an e-Discovery manager.
2. you'll get some kind of 'parameter' error if you select e-Discovery Administrator. It will also unselect you from e-Discovery manager.  You seemingly can only have one.  So re-edit your permissions, and add e-Discovery Manager and remove e-Discovery Administrator.
3. this permission won't kick in for upwards of an hour.
4. If you are using Edge, you are now good.  If you ran your browser as an aministrator, you need a "ClickOnce" browser extension.
5. I found no way to limit the permission of the extension (by site, or by click) and have it work, but perhaps a different extension will work better.

[MS Answers for "You cannot start application Microsoft Office 365 eDiscovery Export Tool from this location because it is already installed from another location"](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/you-cannot-start-application-microsoft-office-365/78d01a51-11c2-47d8-9839-4f92e781c523)

[MS Answers: "EDiscovery error when exporting or previewing: Parameter Preview is not a valid URL option for cmdlet New-ComplianceSearchAction. Parameter name: parameter"](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/ediscovery-error-when-exporting-or-previewing/72f5980a-956a-4a89-ac82-e544cbee1987?page=1)